# Is it idiomatically to say "It is <adverb> doesn't ..."?

Tags: grammar, idioms, indirect-objects, subject-or-object

Several times I met the phrase as: *"It is currently doesn't ..."*, for example *"It is currently doesn't work..."*.

First of all, it seems that the phrase itself is grammatically incorrect, because the verb *"to be"* used in the beginning (*"is"*) implies an object, which seems to be not present here.

However, I am wondering if this phrase could be used and be idiomatic. For example, can we consider as an *object* in this case the whole sentence *"...doesn't work"* (=*"not working"*)?

Comment: "Does" is a main verb or helping verb. is/are don't take helping verbs. Short answer: no.  You can't have both.

Comment: Note that the verb _to be_ cannot be used with objects. Linking verbs (or copulas) like _to be_ link subjects with what is traditionally known as a [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement). So even if this weren’t an ungrammatical sentence (which it is), the thing that comes after _is_ would never be considered an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's simply grammatically incorrect.

One should say "It is currently not working" or "It is currently not in working order" or simply "Currently, it doesn't work".